# USB DAC stopped working after the removal of dedicated GPU

Tags: usb, audio, sound-card

**TL;DR;** My USB DAC stopped working after uninstalling my dedicated GPU.

My PC is running with an i5 12600k and a GTX 1080. Yesterday one of the GPU's fans stopped working, so I uninstalled it and connected my monitor to the DP port on the motherboard, running off of the integrated Intel GPU.

And suddenly, my USB DAC (which supports UAC 2.0) stopped working on this machine. The system recognizes it, and I can select it as the output device, but no sound comes from it. And it happens on both Win 11 and Fedora 38 (I dual boot this machine).

A few things I've tried:

- Tried different USB port
- Tried a USB hub
- Tried different cables
- Tried updating drivers
- Tried uninstalling the DAC

None of them worked.

And a few things:

- My other USB DACs still work on this machine
- This DAC works on my Windows laptops

This is so weird that I don't know how to approach it further. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Update 1:

`sudo dmesg` outputs:

```
[ 1159.520826] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 510
[ 1159.520831] NVRM: No NVIDIA GPU found.
[ 1159.521715] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered Nvlink Core, major device number 510
[ 1160.490502] usb 1-9.3: USB disconnect, device number 22
[ 1160.815178] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 510
[ 1160.815182] NVRM: No NVIDIA GPU found.
[ 1160.815887] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered Nvlink Core, major device number 510
[ 1162.098442] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 510
[ 1162.098447] NVRM: No NVIDIA GPU found.
[ 1162.099176] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered Nvlink Core, major device number 510
[ 1163.240125] usb 1-9.3: new high-speed USB device number 23 using xhci_hcd
[ 1163.333375] usb 1-9.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1fc9, idProduct=300d, bcdDevice= 2.01
[ 1163.333378] usb 1-9.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1163.333379] usb 1-9.3: Product: Monitor 09 III
[ 1163.333380] usb 1-9.3: Manufacturer: MUSILAND Audio Lab
[ 1163.390035] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 510
[ 1163.390039] NVRM: No NVIDIA GPU found.
[ 1163.390864] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered Nvlink Core, major device number 510
[ 1164.674355] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 510
[ 1164.674359] NVRM: No NVIDIA GPU found.
[ 1164.675050] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered Nvlink Core, major device number 510
[ 1165.982251] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 510
[ 1165.982255] NVRM: No NVIDIA GPU found.
[ 1165.983012] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered Nvlink Core, major device number 510
```

Update 2:

Saying "My other USB DACs still work on this machine" is not exactly accurate. On Fedora, I tried to listen to music/videos with one of my other DACs, and it's stuttering like crazy...

Comment: unplug the device, then plug it in, what do you see as the last few lines of `sudo dmesg` (in linux obviously)

Comment: @JaromandaX Question updated with the output of `sudo dmesg`

Comment: wow, so when you plug in that USB device, you get a bunch of messages regarding `nvidia-nvlink` ... interesting

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't think that's what's happening. Those `nvidia-nvlink`-related messages kept popping up regardless of what I was doing. They were generated due to the missing Nvidia card, I suppose. Could that be the cause? Like because the system was busy looking for the missing GPU it couldn't handle the USB DAC properly, hence the failure/stutter.